# Creating web scene from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, web-scene

I am trying to create a web scene from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online. However, I am running into a lot of issues, the most annoying one being that I am running into a very vague warning. Through using the Share tab to share the scene as a web scene and then analysing it, I am able to get the ERRORS to 0 and the WARNINGS to 1, but the warning is a very vague warning that reads [Warning 24080: Ensure scene is authored correctly before sharing](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/analyzer-warning-messages/24080-ensure-scene-is-authored-correctly-before-sharing.htm). The solution points to [how to author a web scene](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/map-authoring/author-a-web-scene.htm), which gives some things to avoid doing. I went through very carefully and reviewed everything step there, and even watered down my scene to something that isn't very useful for my purposes, but just to get something to actually go through, and still no luck. When I try running any web scene to ArcGIS Online from ArcGIS Pro the process will fail. On ArcGIS Online the WFL will show up, but it will be empty. I have no idea what is going wrong with this.

Ultimately I would like to bring a 3D web scene into ArcGIS Online from ArcGIS Pro, but I can't even get a very basic 2D scene to publish. Has anyone found a solution to this problem? Currently I have to create KML features to get anything over to ArcGIS Online, and even then, it is not recognized in the ArcGIS Online scene viewer. The whole intent of the project I am working on is to produce 3D models on ArcGIS Online to be able to share it with a larger audience than keeping it on ArcGIS Pro on the desktop could provide. I have created some web pages using WebGL, ArcGIS v3, ArcGIS v4 Beta, Cesium, and Google Earth APIs with JavaScipt to see how well one of these workarounds would do, but they are a lot of work and they are not as easily integrated with creating story maps from ArcGIS Online in the future.

Recap: Looking for a way to bring my 3D scene in ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online as a web scene. Share As Web Scene in ArcGIS Pro is not working for me, and I can't figure out why.

---

I am not using multipatch features, extrusions, feature classes with over 2000 features, or 3D symbology. My scene is in global mode as well. As you can see my scene is not very advanced, and even though I want 3D extrusions of the buildings I am not even able to get a scene without 3D Properties to publish.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error and torn out hair, I have figured out a solution to my problem. I was able to successfully publish a web scene to ArcGIS Online from ArcGIS Pro by making sure that there are **NO 3D Layers** within the contents. Even though some of the layers did not actually contain 3D properties, they were still listed under the 3D Layers panel in the contents. This was causing the process to fail because it is over complicating things. Rather, I moved the layers down to the 2D panel so I had **2D LAYERS ONLY**, and it published just fine. In fact, when it published, it published with more warnings (Still 0 errors), one of which still being the same vague warning that I was getting before. Once the web scene has been published, it can be opened in ArcGIS Online and the properties can be adjusted back to 3D (extrusions, cartographic offsets, etc.) and the colors can be adjusted as well. I really hope that this helps a lot of other people looking to use ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Online together.

Answer (score 1):

If you are publishing a multi-patch scene service this is currently not supported in ArcGIS Online. Couple questions:

Also are you publishing this from the globe or a local scene? Local scenes are not supported in the WSV(Web Scene Viewer). 
Are you extruding the features in pro?
What symbols are you using when publishing this scene? If you have a screen grab you can share that would be great.

Comment: I am publishing from a Global Scene, features were extruded the first time I tried but after reading that they wouldn't be supported I got rid of the extrusions and 3D symbols. What exactly is a scene grab?

Comment: screen grab/picture of your scene. And you are correct. The WSV does not support extrusion set in Pro. The WSV can set extrusion in the online viewer and you can play with the web scenes JSON to play around with more complex extrusions like having it set an a field height. Also make sure the feature class you are publishing does not have more then 2000 features.

Comment: I checked and split up any feature classes that had over 2000 features. Still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a 3D scene online, in Pro use "Create a scene layer package."  This will package your 3D data, you can load this package into your AGOL account, and add it to a web scene.